# How do you define a custom DNS search in CloudFoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Using CloudFoundry, is there a way to define a custom DNS search so host names are resolved?

We are using an Ubuntu stem cell and need to reach out to an external server.  Using a FQDN, this works, but would prefer to use the host name only.  Generally, this is in resolve.conf on a Unix/Linux box but wasn't sure how to define this in CloudFoundry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option here would be a [Bosh add-on](https://bosh.io/docs/runtime-config.html#addons).  A Bosh add-on will run on all VMs managed by your Bosh Director.  [Here are some example add-ons](https://bosh.io/docs/addons-common.html).

You'll want to use the [os-conf-release](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/os-conf-release) for your add-on.  It has a job called [search_domain](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/os-conf-release/tree/master/jobs/search_domain) which lets you set the search domain on all of the Bosh deployed VMs.

I haven't tested it, but I believe a manifest like this should work.

```
releases:
- name: os-conf
  version: 12

addons:
- name: search-domain
  jobs:
  - name: search_domain
    release: os-conf
  properties:
    search_domain: my.domain.com
```

That would add `my.domain.com` to the list of search domains in resolv.conf.  Hope that helps!

Comment: bosh2 -e [your bosh director IP or URL] update-runtime-config [the file containing the text in the answer above]

Comment: bosh2 -e [Bosh director IP or URL] update-runtime-config [the file containing the text in the answer above]   bosh2 -e [IP] manifest -d [DEPLOYMENT NAME] > deployment.yml   bosh2 -e 10.3.1.106 deploy -d cf-57944913163a4d4f60d9 deployment.yml    I get Release 'os-conf' doesn't exist.

Comment: I also had to install os-conf.  https://bosh.io/releases/github.com/cloudfoundry/os-conf-release?all=1   and had to try a few versions before I found the one that would work.